What's a good way to stop my cat from going through my jalousie-type window?
I have a window that I often keep open to let some air in. It's a jalousie-type window (pictured below) and my cat always jumps up through it to get to a part of the backyard that does not have an easy access.

The problem is, once he gets there, he can't really go anywhere and too stupid to figure out how to come back in via the window so he often has to be rescued which is a time-consuming process. Not to mention he keeps knocking down the small items I placed on the window sill when he jumps.
Overall, I would rather that he just not pass through the window to begin with. However, I don't want to close the window all the time. He's an outside cat and I often have a window at the front slightly ajar that he can and does pass through anytime. The thing is, he just insists on going through this window, I guess just to sate his curiosity.
What are my options here?
I've contemplated getting some kind of mini zappy wire, kind of like an electric fence that I can stick to the window panes temporarily until he understands that that place is no go but I can't find any on online stores, nor am I savvy enough to know how to make a safe one myself.
Another option I thought of was to buy one of those anti-cat scent sprays and spray it on the window panes but I tried that before for an unrelated thing and my cat was not bothered by it and acted like it didn't exist.

would (temporarily?) meshing it over be an option?

That was my thought too. Bug screen.

@JourneymanGeek my cat tore through the mesh screen that I used before that's why I hadn't considered using it again but maybe I just need to get one made from stronger material...

I suggest a proper cat netting instead of a fly screen. Here's a random example:

As you can see the cat can climb on it without damaging it. The mesh size is bigger than that of a fly screen, so the cat cannot scratch through it either. I've seen this type of netting in black, white and transparent.
It's very important that the mesh is so small that your cat cannot possibly force his head through, otherwise you run the risk of strangulating him. So you shouldn't use some decorative fish net or similar things.

There's also "pet screen," which is a type of insect/fly screen that's designed to resist damage from animals, including cats climbing it. Being a screen to keep insects out, the openings are far too small for a cat's head to fit, making it safe there, and I've seen cats climb it without damage to the screen itself.
